# Makefile:How can I control the partial compilation order when I use 'make -j'?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I write a makefile and I want it to execute the program for some reasons after compiling.
But it is too slow when I only use the command 'make'.So I add argument '-j' to speed up.
I just want it to compile all files first and run the program compiled automatically,but it run the program first before the compilation.
How can I control the order partly?

### makefile

```
all:test run
test:test1.o test2.o test3.o
    gcc test1.o test2.o test3.o -o test
test1:test1.c
    gcc -c test1.c
test2:test2.c
    gcc -c test2.c
test3:test3.c
    gcc -c test3.c
run:
    ./test
```

It may run `./test` first before it compile completely.

Comment: The problem you're seeing is almost certainly due to dependencies being incorrectly specified (or just incomplete).  Please edit your question to include the makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I control the order partly?

You control order by specifying dependencies between targets. A target doesn't get built until its prerequisites have been built.

`run` should depend on `test`:

```
run: test
    ./test

.PHONY: run
```

Since `run` is not a file or directory, it should be marked as `.PHONY` target.

I normally have:

```
run_% : %
    ./$<
.PHONY: run_%
```

So that you can use `make run_this` and `make run_that` and it first builds `this` and `that`.